# Using ActiveSheet.Range().Value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to fill 2 cells with one formula.

Currently I have these lines of code trying to make this work...

```
 A = ActiveCell.Row
cell = [column] + A
ActiveSheet.Range("&[cell]&").Value = afstandmeting
```

Column is a given string containing the column of the 2nd cell.
'cell' is a string which comes out like "BX2130" as an example.
I want to use 'cell' as parameter for 'Activesheet.Range().value

Is there a way to make this work?

---

Edit

Currently I am trying this, but this doesn't seem to work either...

```
A = ActiveCell.Row
cell = [column] + A
ActiveSheet.Range([cell]).Select
ActiveCell.Value = afstandmeting
reistijd = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp([reistijd], 0)
```

'reistijd' is the 1st cell's value.
It won't let me put 'afstandmeting' in the 2nd cell

---

Edit 2

To make sure you would get the same error, here you can see the full code

```
Public Function reistijd(van As String, naar As String, col As String) As String
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" & [naar] & ",%20Nederland&key=AIzaSyArx6tiN8kQZkhwrWFg7PfB_5G04WAd6qI", False
    .send
    endpoint = CStr(.responseXML.SelectSingleNode("//place_id").Text)

    CreateObject ("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units=metric&origins=place_id:" & [van] & "&destinations=place_id:" & [endpoint] & "&key=AIzaSyAV-Ra-J0MlT83FL3JDcz6-hEV9Vk4a7yE", False
    .send
    afstandmeting = CDbl(.responseXML.SelectSingleNode("//element/distance/value").Text) / 1000
    reistijd = CStr(.responseXML.SelectSingleNode("//element/distance/value").Text) / 60
End With
A = ActiveCell.Row
cell = col & A
ActiveSheet.Range(cell).Value = afstandmeting
reistijd = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp([reistijd], 0)End Function
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range(cell).Value = ....`

Comment: I already tried this, but this doesn't seem to work...

Comment: You're making some fundamental errors in using strings in VBA. The double-quotes (") need to surround everything that you want to be part of the string exactly. An ampersand (&) concatenates (joins) two strings end-to-end.

Comment: I tried this to make sure that it wasn't an error i was making myself with just using (cell) or ([cell]). Neither of those seem to work..

Comment: Then your output is not what you think it is for cell. try `cell = column & A` and verify that column is truly a string with `BX`

Comment: column is a string, because I am able to select the cell `BX2130`

Comment: Do not use column as it is a protected variable in vba.  It already means something.

Comment: Get rid of all the `[]` they do not mean what you think they do, also when concatenating a string in vba we use `&` not `+`.

Comment: On which line of your second code do you get the error?

Comment: at `ActiveCell.Value = afstandmeting`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142346/discussion-between-legacyprogrammer-and-scott-craner).

Comment: Then your problem lies in what `afstandmeting` is.

Comment: In the current code the value of `afstandmeting` is `43,669` as it is a double. I can't figure out what could cause this error..

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this:

```
Dim A as Long
Dim cell as string
Dim col as string
Dim afstandmeting as String

col = "BX"
A = ActiveCell.Row
cell = col & A
afstandmeting = "=SUM(A1:B1)"

ActiveSheet.Range(cell).Formula = afstandmeting
```

Comment: `BX` is given as a parameter in the formula. And this doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: Works just fine for me, You must have something else that is causing the problem.  Try running the code above in its own sub.

Comment: This worked.. But I don't have any idea what is causing my problem then.

Comment: Using "Test2" instead of `afstandmeting` as value doesn't seem to work either